# ActionMailer do not use mail layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, email-templates

I have stuck with such problem:
I create MessageMailer < ActionMailer, and it works correct except that it does not take email layouts which I put in the folder view/message_mailer. What is missing for these layout would work?

My files:

> mailers/message_mailer.rb

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :to => "myemail@mail.com"
  def message_me(msg)
    @msg = msg
    mail from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
  end
end
```

> views/message_mailer/message_me.text.erb

```
A question form contact form:

Name: <%= @msg.name %>
Email: <%= @msg.email %>
Contact: <%= @msg.content %>
```

The ActionMailer does not use this template, it just renders a simple email like this:

```
Sent mail to myemail@mail.com (8.2ms)
Date: Sun, 07 Feb 2016 17:19:19 +0300
From: test@test.com
To: myemail@mail.com
Message-ID: <56b752676ac09_491e3fd1eb4f01bc33736@hello.local.mail>
Subject: message subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

There is message content
```

Answer (score 4):

Template not used in your mail because you are using `mail` method with `body:` argument which forces mailer to build email without template.

Find more useful info about rails mailer in [Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering)